# Pytorch: set indices in a particular Tensor dimension (similar to torch.index_select)

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to get and set indices in a particular tensor dimension without reshaping if possible. I've been able to find the `torch.index_select` function which does what I want when getting values, but I haven't found an analogous setter function yet. Does one exist?

For context I have a tensor and a set of indexes

```
class_energy = torch.rand(3, 10, 32, 32)
class_logits = torch.empty_like(class_energy)
idxs = [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

I want to access items at those indices *in a particular dimension* so I can perform a log_softmax.

If I knew dim a-priori then I could simply use the fancy `__getitem__` / `__setitem__` syntax: For example, if `dim=1`, then `class_energy[:, idxs]`. Likewise, if `dim=2` -> `class_energy[:, :, idxs]`, `dim=0` -> `class_energy[idxs]`, etc...

In the case where `dim=1`, I essentially want this:

```
class_logits[:, idxs] = F.log_softmax(class_energy[:, idxs], dim=1)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know the value of `dim` ahead of time. Sure I could build up the fancy index ahead of time via:

```
fancy_index = tuple([slice(None)] * dim + [idxs])
class_logits[fancy_index] = F.log_softmax(class_energy[fancy_index], dim=dim)
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. For the case of `__getitem__`, I know for a fact that there is. The following code using `torch.index_select` is equivalent

```
fancy_index = tuple([slice(None)] * dim + [idxs])
index = torch.LongTensor(idxs).to(class_energy.device)
class_logits[fancy_index] = F.log_softmax(torch.index_select(class_energy, dim=dim, index=index, dim=dim))
```

Not only is it functionally the same, index_select is much faster (I've seen 2x improvement) than using the fancy getitem syntax.

My issue is that I can't seem to similar functionality for the `__setitem__` portion of the code. It would be really nice if I could get rid of the fancy index all together. I've looked into `Tensor.put_`, `torch.index_put`, and `torch.select`, but none of these seem to have the functionality I want. Is there something I'm missing, or is the fancy index the only way to solve this problem currently?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood what you looking for, but did you try `index_copy`?:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_copy_

This lets you copy a tensor to the specified index using an index tensor and dim, in the documentation there is an example. (There is also an **out-of-place** version `index_copy`)

Comment: This seems to work. I'm now getting speeds roughly 2x that of the fancy indexing method. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it helps!